# Unusual table reduction in Pandas or SQL

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a database table similar to the following bogus sample (but with many thousands of records):

```
LastName FirstName MiddleInit Company   Team             LogDate
   smith    joseph          a   compA  teama 2015-09-18 23:00:00
   smith    joseph          a   compA  teamb 2015-08-15 04:00:00
   smith    joseph          a   compA  teamc 2015-10-01 02:15:00
    lamb      mary          b   compA  teama 2015-09-15 23:00:00
    lamb      mary          b   compA  teamb 2015-10-04 01:15:00
    lamb      mary          b   compA  teamc 2015-05-01 07:00:00
    brady    thomas         c   compB  teama 2015-10-02 03:15:00
    brady    thomas         c   compB  teamb 2015-09-11 20:00:00
    brady    thomas         c   compB  teamc 2015-06-02 05:00:00
    smith      john         d   compB  teama 2015-09-12 08:00:00
    smith      john         d   compB  teamb 2015-10-05 09:15:00
    smith      john         d   compB  teamc 2015-07-03 15:00:00
```

The included people stay with the same company, but they move from team to team.  **I am interested in finding out the most recent team each person was on based on the LogDate field**.  Here is the output I would like to produce (order of names doesn’t matter):

```
LastName FirstName MiddleInit Company   Team             LogDate
   smith    joseph          a   compA  teamc 2015-10-01 02:15:00
    lamb      mary          b   compA  teamb 2015-10-04 01:15:00
   brady    thomas          c   compB  teama 2015-10-02 03:15:00
   smith      john          d   compB  teamb 2015-10-05 09:15:00
```

**I would like to know if there is a way to derive this output using a single SQL query or using Pandas** (preferably without loops).

Attempt using SQL: I don’t have access to the database as I’m writing this, but I had to join two tables to get the Team field, and I think I unsuccessfully tried something along the lines of (this may not be completely right but should be close to what I tried):

```
SELECT a.LastName, a.FirstName, a.MiddleInit, a.Company, b.Team, max(b.LogDate) FROM table1 AS a JOIN table2 AS b ON a.LastName=b.LastName AND a.FirstName=b.FirstName AND a.MiddleInit=b.MiddleInit AND a.Company=b.Company GROUP BY a.LastName, a.FirstName, a.MiddleInit, a.Company ORDER BY a.LastName, a.FirstName, a.MiddleInit, a.Company;
```

Attempt using Pandas:
As an experiment, I loaded the above table using a CSV, and wrote a quick Python script:

```
import pandas as pd
td1 = pd.read_csv('teamdata.csv',parse_dates=['LogDate'])
td2 = td1.groupby(['LastName','FirstName','MiddleInit','Company']).max().reset_index()
```

But this always returns “teamc” as the team, not the team that corresponds to the row with the most recent LogDate:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: td1 = pd.read_csv('teamdata.csv',parse_dates=['LogDate'])

In [3]: td2 = td1.groupby(['LastName','FirstName','MiddleInit','Company']).max().reset_index()

In [4]: td2
Out[4]:
  LastName FirstName MiddleInit Company   Team             LogDate
0    brady    thomas          c   compB  teamc 2015-10-02 03:15:00
1     lamb      mary          b   compA  teamc 2015-10-04 01:15:00
2    smith      john          d   compB  teamc 2015-10-05 09:15:00
3    smith    joseph          a   compA  teamc 2015-10-01 02:15:00
```

Even if I use a custom function for the groupby, my understanding is that it will only act on the column being processed (LogDate) and I don’t know a way to reference the Team that was in that particular record.  Any ideas are appreciated, preferably without resorting to loops or multiple SQL queries, but if that’s the only way it can be done I’d take anything at this point.  Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want in Postgres is using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (lastname, firstname, middleinit, company) t.*
from table1 t
order by lastname, firstname, middleinit, company, logdate desc;
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you!  I had tried DISTINCT with incorrect results but being fairly new to PostgreSQL I wasn’t aware of DISTINCT ON.  For future readers trying to do something similar in another DBMS, this post may be helpful: [link](http://www.noelherrick.com/blog/postgres-distinct-on)

Answer (score 1):

In pandas you could use `idxmax` to get the indicies of the max for each group:

```
In [17]: df.loc[df.groupby(['LastName','FirstName','MiddleInit','Company'])['LogDate'].idxmax(), :]
Out[17]: 
   LastName FirstName MiddleInit Company   Team             LogDate
6     brady    thomas          c   compB  teama 2015-10-02 03:15:00
4      lamb      mary          b   compA  teamb 2015-10-04 01:15:00
10    smith      john          d   compB  teamb 2015-10-05 09:15:00
2     smith    joseph          a   compA  teamc 2015-10-01 02:15:00
```

Comment: +1 Another great answer!  I wound up using the SQL approach figuring that was more efficient, but I’m keeping this example around because I’m sure I’ll need it some time in the future.  Thank you!